# Localhost to custom page

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I am running macOS 10.12.5 and I am setting up a localhost and everything looks correct.  I used brew to install Apache (httpd), MySQL, and PHP.  I have changed the hosts file to point the localhost to the custom site and changed the vhost to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/me/site"
  <Directory /Users/me/site/>
    ServerName me.com
    ServerAlias www.me.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>`
```

I have updated httpd.conf to include the vhost file and the appropriate php modules needed.

When accessing 'localhost' by either 127.0.0.1 or the site name itself I receive the `It Works!` page instead of the files located in

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/me/site"
<Directory /Users/me/site/>
```

Note: I am using brew to initialize apache and when using `which httpd` I am seeing `/usr/local/bin/httpd`.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have some errors in the config snippet you posted, try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/site"
    ServerName me.com
    ServerAlias www.me.com
    ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog /private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

You don't need to `<Directory>` section for these directives, and you were missing the closing `</Directory>`. This might have caused Apache to not load your config and serve the default virtualhost instead.

Comment: After making the edits, I still have the same issue happening, localhost is still coming up with It Works!

Comment: @Alcyeonnero I have the same doubts as @klanomath, are you sure you edited `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf`, not `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`?

Comment: I have edited the `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf` and changed the vhost file in `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhost` and I am still getting "It Works"

Comment: I am using brew to initialize apache and when using `which httpd` I am seeing `/usr/local/bin/httpd`.